# How to destroy LightningOutApp

Tags: lightning, visualforce-component, lightning-out

Can anyone please help me. I have implemented the LightningOut using visual force page to call a lightning component. When I am trying to destroy the lightning component using destroy() which is destroying the component but the LightningOutApp is still there which is causing issue while I am trying load another component. Is there any way to destroy LightningOutApp as well!!

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for isn't directly supported. The only reasonable way to clear the app is to reload the page somehow (it must be a full reload, not a partial render). You can do this with an apex:actionFunction or another technique that causes a page render.

However, it's worth noting that you can have multiple components in your dependency app, then switch between them as you desire. The reason why you even need the dependency app is because the bits of the runtime responsible for loading components only exist in Salesforce1 and the One App (Lightning Experience).

To work around this limitation, Lightning Out downloads all the metadata for all dependencies in the dependency app when it is first loaded. This is also why there's a limitation of one app per page. Your components will take slightly longer to load upfront, but will be fully responsive later.

Alternatively, you could write a third component that dynamically switches between the two with aura:if, and have that be the top-level component. This technique works well in most cases.